# mongoose insertMany wont execute

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Node version v8.13.0
Mongoose 5.3.13"

i have try to insert **1 million** record

```
Contact.insertMany(dataArry,{ ordered: false }, function(err, result) {
        console.info(err);
        console.info(result)

    });
```

but it wont execute
after some seconds it showing error is null and results is empty array

Comment: It looks like MongoDB has a [maxWriteBatchSize](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Write-Command-Batch-Limit-Size)  which you're exceeding.`maxWriteBatchSize` is *100,000* only for MongoDB 3.6 and above.

Comment: But is also mentioned that the `MongoDB driver` should split it and then send the write request to the `MongoDB Server`.

Comment: thank you @SumanKundu , i tried 100,000 but it wont execute only inserted 4865 record

Comment: Can you try that exact same with using `mongodb driver` for `nodejs`? I'm also curious, looks like `mongoose` related problem.

Comment: thank you @SumanKundu mongodb driver is working fine,but it want execute  1,000,000  parallelly 10 more task

Comment: read [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#what-type-of-locking-does-mongodb-use)